# how to style an arrow od select drop down box in html?

Tags: html, select

I only want to change arrow in select box with my own custom arrow without using any javascript and jquery.
Any help?

Comment: Good luck with that! (Seriously; though I don't *think* it can be done (*reliably*) without JavaScript and using a native `select` element, but I'd be interested to find out I'm wrong about that!)

Comment: Without JS? No. With a little JS? Yes. There are some CSS tricks to this, but afaik, none are 100% reliable.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Answer (score 2):

i could not understand you clearly..

here is my thought and suggestion:
html:

```
<div class="my_checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" value="None" id="my_checkbox" name="check">
<label for="my_checkbox"></label>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.my_checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:after {
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
opacity: 1;
}
```

for all: [click me](http://cssdeck.com/labs/z7nvb163)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It's rendered by the OS, not the browser. There are hack work-arounds using absolute positioning but the control itself cannot be reliably styled across browsers.

Comment: So can anyone sggest me a code by which i can implemented this in minimum required code?

Comment: You have not explained the desired result.

Comment: the cleanest solution would be to completely rebuild the select with javascript have a look at http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jqtransform